# Check that a DB link is actually pointing to the right server

Tags: oracle

I am currently trying to validate that an Oracle db_link is actually pointing to the correct server.
When I query the db_links I get the definition of the DB_link referencing the TNSNames:

```
select * from all_db_links;
```

Gives me the following result:

OWNER: user1
DB_LINK: DBL_xxx.world
Username: User2
Host: tnsEntry1
Created: 03-MAY-12

When I test the DB_link, everything works fine:

```
select * from dual@"DBL_xxx.world";
```

> DUMMY: X

However, as I do not have access to the server, I cannot make sure that the tns entry tnsEntry1 is pointed to the correct server.

Locally, I can run:

```
select sys_context ( 'USERENV', 'DB_NAME' ) db_name,
 sys_context ( 'USERENV', 'SESSION_USER' ) user_name,
 sys_context ( 'USERENV', 'SERVER_HOST' ) db_host
 from dual;
```

I tried to run the same command remotely:

```
select sys_context ( 'USERENV', 'DB_NAME' ) db_name,
 sys_context ( 'USERENV', 'SESSION_USER' ) user_name,
 sys_context ( 'USERENV', 'SERVER_HOST' ) db_host
 from dual@DBL_xxx.world;
```

But it returns only local data.

Is there a way to check the remote info? Or check the tnsnames from a sql query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will give you the database name of the database on the other end of the database link:

```
select property_value 
from database_properties@<database_link> 
where property_name='GLOBAL_DB_NAME'
```

Comment: we also figured out that: SELECT
    instance_name,
    host_name,
    startup_time
FROM
    v$instance@<database_link>;
would return the info.